# Celery running Signature from Database (AttributeError: object has no attribute 'oid' --> opts['reply_to'] = self.app.oid)

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I have a *jobs* and *tasks* in my implementation. *Jobs* are basically functions with arguments and they are returning `Signature` (1 *task*) or `_chain` (2 or more *tasks* chained), which some of them are *mutable* and some *immutable*).

I am combining multiple *Jobs* by creating a *chain* of `Signature` or `_chain` that each *Job* is returning.

App requirements:

Broker: *RabbitMQ*

Result Backend: *PostgreSQL*

Packages:

```
celery==4.3.0
kombu==4.6.7
```

Example:

```
def example_job_1(arg_1, arg_2, **kwargs):
    example_task_1_s = task_1.si(arg_1)
    example_task_2_s = task_2.s(arg_2)
    return example_task_1_s | example_task_2_s

def example_job_2(arg_1, arg_2, **kwargs):
    return task_1.si(arg_1)


signature = example_job_1(arg_1, arg_2) | example_job_2(arg_1) # _chain object
```

Some of this *signatures* I am running immediately (and that's okay) but some *signatures* I am saving into the Database. The goal is, if needed, to retrieve *signatures* from Database and run those *signatures* later.

For *Signature* --> *JSON* and *JSON* --> *Signature* I am ussing following two functions:

```
import json
from celery.canvas import Signature
flatten = jsonpickle.pickler.Pickler().flatten
restore = jsonpickle.unpickler.Unpickler().restore

def signature_dumps(obj: Signature) -> str:
    """
    Serialize celery signature object to string
    :param obj: celery.canvas:Signature
    :return: str
    """
    return json.dumps(flatten(obj), indent=2)


def signature_loads(s: str) -> Signature:
    """
    Create celery signature object from string value
    :param s: string representation of signature
    :return: celery.canvas:Signature object
    """
    return restore(json.loads(s))
```

At some point, I am reaching to the Database, I am retrieving *Signatures* objects. Some of them are `instanceof(object, Signature)` and some of them are `instanceof(object, _chain)`, than I am chaining those object into *chain*.

Example:

```
object_1 # Signature
object_2 # Signature
object_3 # _chain

ch = object_1 | object_2 | object_3
ch.apply_async()
```

`apply_async` here Raised:

```
opts['reply_to'] = self.app.oid
AttributeError: '{task inside object_3 _chain}' object has no attribute 'oid'
```

When I *chain* only `Signature` objects, I don't receive this message. But if there is any `_chain` object that I retrieved from the database and convert, I am getting this error.

I noticed when I go to the database and get all `Signature` objects, and do `apply_async` on each, all `Signatures` passed except `_chain` objects.

Error:

```
 if app.conf.task_always_eager:
AttributeError: 'task_1' object has no attribute 'conf'
```

In both of these errors, I noticed that `self.app` object return `task_1` (task it self, and not instance of Celery App object) which is case for the rest.

The same for previous exception `self.app.iod`, `app` is refering to `task_1` instead of `Celery` instance.

Is it possible that Dumping/Restoring Chain signature from DB is not working properly?

What's missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So guys, I have found out solution to this problem.

After some time, I take 1 *Job* which returns *_chain* object with some *dummy* argument values.

I used same mentioned functions above `signature_dumps` and `signature_loads` to dump *Signature* in *file* (I wanted to check if something is corrupted while signature is stored in Database, desperate move). After loading signature from *File* and running `.apply_async()`, everything worked.

After this successful test, I tried manually to *copy*/*paste* content from DB to my file, loaded content and tried to run `.apply_async()`, but again I got mentioned error above.

I wanted to see, what is the difference from *Signature* I created with my *dummy* values and *Signature* stored in DB (I used online diff checker) and there were two main differences:

*Signature* with *dummy* values

```
"options": {},
  "subtask_type": "chain",
  "task": "celery.chain",
  "__dict__": {
    "_app": {
      "py/id": 2
    },
    "_frozen": null,
    "_use_link": null
  }
```

*Signature* from DB

```
"options": {},
  "subtask_type": "chain",
  "task": "celery.chain",
  "__dict__": {
    "_app": {
      "py/id": 3
    },
    "_frozen": null,
    "_use_link": null
  }
```

This line `"py/id": 3` was one of this two main differences. I tried to found out if *Celery App* instance has some identifier, and that's causing it, but it wasn't the case.

Second difference was that in my *dummy* *Signature* and real *Signature* was that I provided all *dummy* values - *String*, *Int*, ... and in my real *Signature* from database I had *UUID* instance provided.

After this, I created new *_chain* *Signature* with *dummy* values and 1 argument was *UUID* instance, and then I got this `"py/id": 3` in my *dummy* *Signature*. After that, loading and running this *Signature* failed with the same error as *Signature* from Database.

Providing *String* instead of *UUID* instance solved my problem!

What actually caused an errror?

By default, *Celery* is using *JSON* serialization and content, and as mentioned above, I am using *jsonpickle* to *Pickle* *Signature* to and from Database. After *Unpickle*-ing *Signature* from database, with complex object, I gave to *Celery* instance object which was *Unpickled*, and he didn't know how to Serialize and Read this content properly.

So, be careful what are you providing to your *Celery Tasks* and what are your *Configs* for *Acept Content* and *Serialization* in *Celery App*